# Generalized Idempotency of Multi-variable Function

Tags: functional-analysis, functions, idempotents

I am wondering what a generalization of idempotency would look like for a function of multiple variables.

For instance, for basic idempotency of a function of one variable, we have: 
`f(f(x)) = f(x)`.

Suppose we have a function `g` such that `g(x, g(y,z)) = g(x, y, z)`. What is more, the previous statement is true, no matter where we place the inner `g`.

That is, the following is also true: `g(g(x, y), z)) = g(x, y, z)`. In a sense, the latter simply demonstrates the associativity of the operation `g`.

The question is whether the type of above function can be considered idempotent. What is idempotence for a function of several variables? Could this be called partial idempotence?

Comment: Your $g$s seem to be confused as to whether they have two or three arguments.

Comment: `g` has a variable but finite arity. I am illustrating with a simple example.

Comment: Then you seem to have rediscovered semigroups: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semigroup

Comment: *because the condition you've given is usually called associativity. Admittedly you note this, but then your question confuses me.

Comment: Yes, but isn't there an issue with semi-groups needing a binary operation? My `g` is n-ary?

Comment: But your $n$-ary operation is uniquely determined by the 2-ary version of it.

Comment: In fact if you require $g$ to have a 0-ary version, I think this is a monoid.

Comment: Could you explain? I think this deserves an answer :)

Comment: Yeah I agree, I'm eating lunch rn tho, so I'll write it up after

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer will hopefully expand on and clarify my comments on the question.

First let's formalize what we want from $g$. You'll definitely want to look at [the Operad article on Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operad_theory), specifically the section on [the associative operad.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operad_theory#Associative_operad) However, I'll try to avoid using the idea of operads in the rest of my answer.

$g$ is a family of $n$-ary operations for $n\ge 2$, thought of as operations on an underlying set $S$, so $g_n : S^n \to S$. The "generalized idempotency" property that you want seems like it can be written formally as 
$$g_n(x_1,\ldots,x_n) = g_{n-1}(x_1,\ldots,x_{i-1},g_2(x_i,x_{i+1}),x_{i+2},\ldots,x_n)$$
for any $1\le i < n$ and all choices of $x_i\in S$. I claim that this forces $g_2$ to be an associative product, and $g_n$ to be the $n$th finite product, so $g$ contains the same information as a semigroup on $S$.

Then $g_2(x,g_2(y,z))=g_3(x,y,z)=g_2(g_2(x,y),z)$, so $g_2$ is an associative product. Moreover, if $(S,\cdot)$ is a semigroup, the $n$th product operation, $\Pi_n : S^n \to S$ is defined inductively by $\Pi_1(x_1)=x_1$, and $$\Pi_n(x_1,\ldots,x_n) = \Pi_{n-1}(x_1,\ldots,x_{n-1}\cdot x_n).$$

Now if the semigroup is given by the operation $g_2$, which I will now denote by $\cdot$ for brevity, we want to prove that $g_n=\Pi_n$ for $n\ge 2$. We can prove this inductively.
First note $\Pi_2(x_1,x_2)=\Pi_1(x_1\cdot x_2)=x_1\cdot x_2=g_2(x_1,x_2)$, so $g_2=\Pi_2$. Now if $g_n=\Pi_n$, then
$$ \Pi_{n+1}(x_1,\ldots,x_n,x_{n+1})
=
\Pi_n(x_1,\ldots,x_n\cdot x_{n+1})
=
g_n(x_1,\ldots,x_n\cdot x_{n+1})
=
g_{n+1}(x_1,\ldots,x_n,x_{n+1})
$$
by definition of $\Pi_{n+1}$, the inductive hypothesis, and the given property of $g_n$. Hence the induction holds. Thus a family $g_n$ on $S$ with the given property for $n\ge 2$ is equivalent to the data of a semigroup on $S$.

Generalizing the condition given slightly, we can ask about extending the definition to families of operations $g_n$ for $n\ge 1$ or $n\ge 0$.
Note that the condition given generalizes straightforwardly to families $g_n$ for $n\ge N_0$ subject to the condition that
$$g_n(x_1,\ldots,x_i,g_m(x_{i+1},\ldots,x_{i+m}),x_{i+m+1},\ldots,x_{n+m-1}) = g_{n+m-1}(x_1,\ldots,x_{n+m-1}),$$
for all $n,m\ge N_0$, $n\ge 1$, and all choices of $x_1,\ldots,x_{n+m-1}\in S$. We for $N_0\le 2$, we still have that $g_2$ is an associative binary operation and $g_n=\Pi_n$, so we just need to examine what properties $g_1$ and $g_0$ have when defined. 
First note that the condition given implies that $g_1(g_1(x_1))=g_1(x_1)$, so $g_1$ is idempotent. (Justifying calling the given condition generalized idempotence in a sense.) Now let $T\subset S$ be the image of $g_1$. Since $g_1(g_2(x_1,x_2))=g_2(x_1,x_2)$, $g_2$ induces a well defined operation $T\times T \to T$, making $T$ a semigroup. Then $g_2(x_1,x_2)=g_2(g_1(x_1),g_1(x_2))$, so the semigroup operation on $S$ is induced by the semigroup operation on $T$, so the data of $g_n$ for $n\ge 1$ is equivalent to two sets $T\subset S$, an associative binary operation on $T$, $g_2|_{T\times T}$,
and a map $g_1:S\to T$ restricting to the identity on $T$.

Finally if we add $g_0$, then $g_0=g_1(g_0)\in T$, and $g_2(x_1,g_0)=g_1(x_1)=g_2(g_0,x_1)$, so the semigroup $T$ has an identity element $g_0$. Thus the semigroup on $T$ is in fact a monoid in this case. Hence the data of $g_n$ for $n\ge 0$ is equivalent to a pair of sets $T\subset S$, a monoid structure on $T$, and a map $S\to T$ restricting to the identity on $T$.

Last note, it's also interesting to consider what happens when you choose $N_0 > 2$, i.e. where there is no binary operation generating the whole structure. However, it gets a lot more complicated in that case, so I can't say anything about it.

Comment: Thank you. Would it change anything if I also imposed the condition that it is possible to have `g(x) = x`? That is, `g` is also unary.

Comment: Ah that's the case where you extend the family to include a unary operation, disccussed towards the end. In that case, $g_1$ is the identity, and hence $T=S$. Thus in that case, if you don't include a $g_0$, nothing changes. If you do include a $g_0$, you get a multiplicative identity and $S$ becomes a monoid.

Comment: Excellent! You have great skills :)

Comment: Also, I m wondering if the signs on `m` and `1` should be reversed in the subscript of $$g_{n+m-1}(x_1,\ldots,x_{n+m-1}),$$ ?

Comment: @MadPhysicist Ah, no, that's because on the LHS you have $g_m$ taking $m$ arguments and $g_n$ taking another $n-1$ arguments in addition to the result of $g_m$, so on the RHS we should get a total of $m + n -1 =n+m-1$ arguments.